# Count query help needed with unique records

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I have this following data-structure and I am trying to find unique ID where value Alphabets value **Equals** to A and B (i.e. select ID = 1, but not ID = 3 or 5). 
and also find unique ID where value Alphabets values contains **Both** A and B (i.e. select ID = 1, 3 and 5).

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ ID         ║ Alphabets   ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 1          ║ A           ║
║ 1 ║ 1          ║ B           ║
║ 4 ║ 2          ║ B           ║
║ 5 ║ 2          ║ D           ║
║ 6 ║ 3          ║ A           ║
║ 7 ║ 3          ║ B           ║
║ 8 ║ 3          ║ D           ║
║ 9 ║ 4          ║ A           ║
║ 10║ 4          ║ C           ║
║ 11║ 5          ║ A           ║
║ 12║ 5          ║ B           ║
║ 13║ 5          ║ C           ║
║ 14║ 5          ║ D           ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝

CREATE TABLE dbo.Alphabets(
ID int NOT NULL
,Alphabets char(1) NOT NULL
,CONSTRAINT PK_Alphabets PRIMARY KEY (ID, Alphabets)
);


INSERT INTO dbo.Alphabets VALUES
 (1, 'A')
,(1, 'B')
,(2, 'B')
,(2, 'D')
,(3, 'A')
,(3, 'B')
,(3, 'D')
,(4, 'A')
,(4, 'C')
,(5, 'A')
,(5, 'B')
,(5, 'C')
,(5, 'D');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Alphabets
WHERE Alphabets IN ('A','B')

EXCEPT

SELECT ID
FROM Alphabets
WHERE Alphabets NOT IN ('A','B')
```

There are many other ways to accomplish the task, but this is one of the simplest.

A more obscure (but more efficient) solution in a single pass uses aggregation and a CASE expression:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Alphabets
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Alphabets IN ('A','B') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly. 
I plan to use the more efficient HAVING solution instead of the EXCEPT join.

Comment: hey @spaghettidba, another query.....how about if I wanted to select ID=1,3, and 5?? that is all records having **both** A and B

Comment: @Deb `SELECT ID
FROM Alphabets
WHERE Alphabets IN ('A','B') 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`

Comment: thanks, that also works perfectly fine. I have also updated the question now...... :)

Comment: Both queries are not what the OP wants. it will include IDs with only A or B: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56002/2

Comment: @ypercube both queries are what the op wanted originally. The question was edited afterwards

Comment: I'm not talking about the additional question but the first one. The *"where value Alphabets value Equals to A and B (i.e. select ID = 1, but not ID = 3 or 5)"* seems to me that it wants IDs that have both A and B (and not anything else). But I could be wrong, since they accepted.

Comment: @ypercube I think we'll never know. Oh well, problem solved, let's move on. :)